# i7-8700 & 20.04 - PassMark is way below "average" - 10300 vs 13300 median

Tags: 20.04, performance, benchmarks

I recently moved some edge/IoT machines from an i5-10500T platform to an i7-8700 platform.  Immediately after deploying some of the first machines I could just "feel" that they were slower, but couldn't determine why.  After A LOT of PassMark testing I couldn't get anywhere about 10,800 on the i7-8700, where the median score on cpubenchmark is 13300+.

So, for comparison, I wondered what the "old" machines would test at - they scored 10,736 which is about as close to the median of 10,742 as you can get.

Why are these i7-8700's so much "slower" than the i5-10700T?  If the median PassMark score is 13,300 for the i7-8700, why can't I even get above 11,000?  I've enabled SpeedStep, Turbo Mode, I've used tuned-adm to set the profile to throughput-performance -- nothing has even moved the needle.  They are just stuck at 10,800 -- the same PassMark score as an i5-10700T.

I'm at my wits end.  I've spent hours researching, reading, making changes.  I even downgraded to 18.04 to see if there was a diffence.  Nada.  I tried different versions of BIOS, nada.

I'm interested in any possible ideas to help troubleshoot this.  Here are the PassMark results from the "old" i5 and the "new" i7:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10500T CPU @ 2.30GHz (x86_64)
6 cores @ 3800 MHz  |  7.6 GiB RAM
Number of Processes: 12  |  Test Iterations: 1  |  Test Duration: Medium
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Mark:                          10958
  Integer Math                     37717 Million Operations/s
  Floating Point Math              23439 Million Operations/s
  Prime Numbers                    37 Million Primes/s
  Sorting                          23928 Thousand Strings/s
  Encryption                       4892 MB/s
  Compression                      136 MB/s
  CPU Single Threaded              2269 Million Operations/s
  Physics                          808 Frames/s
  Extended Instructions (SSE)      5872 Million Matrices/s
```

versus:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (x86_64)
6 cores @ 4600 MHz  |  7.7 GiB RAM
Number of Processes: 12  |  Test Iterations: 1  |  Test Duration: Medium
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Mark:                          10816
  Integer Math                     40672 Million Operations/s
  Floating Point Math              26083 Million Operations/s
  Prime Numbers                    20 Million Primes/s
  Sorting                          17248 Thousand Strings/s
  Encryption                       5263 MB/s
  Compression                      157 MB/s
  CPU Single Threaded              2987 Million Operations/s
  Physics                          442 Frames/s
  Extended Instructions (SSE)      8256 Million Matrices/s
```

and relevant cpu info:

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 4.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 4.60 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 4.45 GHz.


cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xb4
cpu MHz     : 4519.046
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds
bogomips    : 6384.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: What was the i7-8700 used for previously? Does it have a history of being overclocked or under-volted? Is the system able to "breathe" well enough to dissipate the heat caused by the hotter-running i7? The biggest issues I've seen with CPU performance have generally been the result of thermal throttling more than anything else 